# Deleting DOM nodes in JavaScript to save Memory

Tags: javascript, dom, memory

I am using Safari browser for viewing my Web Page which is rich in Javascript. I see Safari takes a lot of memory (500-900 MBs) while viewing the web page and doing various operations. I wish to know whether deleting the DOM objects created, using say, `var elem = document.getElementById('Id1');` needs to be deleted for optimizing this memory utilization? If any other pointers, please suggest. Also, how can we delete this DOM object in the simplest way?

Thanks
Siddharth

Answer (score 1):

One point of clarification. Your example code does not *create* a DOM node; it merely retrieves a reference to an *existing node*:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('Id1');
```

Once you have access to the element you can remove it like this:

```
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Deleting DOM nodes may be useless** if you're creating memory leaks (they may not be cleared from memory).

This can happen if you connect DOM nodes & javascript objects within your code (circular references that won't be cleared by DOM and JS Garbage Collectors).

If you want to get rid of this problem:

- use the tools mentionned [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077739/deleting-dom-nodes-in-javascript-to-save-memory/5077895#5077895)
- read a little bit on [DOM/JS memory leaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448%28VS.85%29.aspx) if you want to avoid future leaks and recognize this anti-pattern.

Comment: depends in which way you connect them. if it's in some variable in a function, then nothing bad will happen, but if it persists in memory, either by referencing a node in a global or in some other way which is could be accessible later, then it's a problem

Answer (score 0):

The webkit inspector has a profiler utility for this kind of thing. I'm not sure if it exists in the Safari version but it's definitely in the Chrome version.

See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028479/finding-memory-leaks-in-javascript-using-firebug/5028545#5028545).

[Here](http://mactips.info/2010/07/use-safari-5s-web-inspector) is a good tutorial on using the Safari Inspector utility.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am already using this kit, but I am unable to find the exact way to detect memory leaks or ways of optimizing these memory leaks.

Comment: You can use the profiles tab to profile the page, and use the "take heap snapshot" function in the profile to so see what elements, objects, variables are using large amounts of memory.