# Memory issue in high resolution image loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a image gallery application. When a user click a thumbnail of a gallery image it will show the actual high resolution image (nearly 2000x1500). For the faster viewing I have added pre-loading of images.The main problem noticed in this application is

The memory utilization increases substantially in ie8 when viewing the actual high resolution images. I have tested the jQuery lightbox plugin in ie8. Still the issue is light box too.. How can resolve this issue? It it a general issue of ie8 ? If there is any solution available please share with me !

Comment: Test your code with http://www.outofhanwell.com/ieleak/index.php?title=Main_Page see also my answer about memory leaks in IE here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5028653/22470

Comment: Does increase based on the size of the images, or do you have a leak as well?

Comment: The solution is to NOT preloading the images on browser. If some one wish to load this big image, he know at advanced that must wait this load. Did this problem go way on chrome ? I think that IE8 have speed issues with big images, and on ie9 advertize that they fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If your image format is BMP or PNG then convert into a jpg beacause BMP and PNG image size is much bigger then JPG. i suggest use JPG Image