# how to find a memory leak and debug a jquery/javascript application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, memory, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to degub a fairly large application written in jquery mobile and am struggling to pin down a suspected memory leak.

I have been criss-crossing through the app running all functions up and down. all the while server memory usage is ok and all but one page are working fine.

On the page in question (widget heavy product search  & order page, using JQM photoswipe, multiview plus a bunch of other plugins) all works well for a while until most of the buttons stop working.

Buttons not reacting tells me I need to check my jquery app manager, which also handles all event bindings. problem is, it's about 90k and I don't really know where to start, so

**Question**:  
are there any tools that can check Jquery/Javascript for potential memory leaks? What else could I do to try and pin down the problem?

Thanks for some insights

Comment: Besides the buttons not working, what evidence do you have that the problem is a memory leak?  Have you looked in the error console for script errors?  Have you set a breakpoint in the event handler for the button?

Comment: You're probably looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028479/finding-memory-leaks-in-javascript-using-firebug

Comment: there are no errors in firebug. actually the app/page is running smooth on dekstop, while on ipad1+3, I'm running into the page stall. I'm using set a bunch of consoles, also inside the event bindings, but once the page stalls, they are not firing anymore either.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out some of what the Chrome Developer Tools has to offer. I've done memory profiling and identified some memory leaks that way:

- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling
- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks

Comment: Thanks. I will try and have a look!